# running python in android app with chaquopy yields fatal error

Tags: android, chaquopy

I'm try to run python code in my android app using Chaquopy, I'm also using the moviepy library (I'm converting a mp4 file to a gif file). When I try to do the conversion I get the following error message:

```
2019-02-06 15:46:47.586 3924-3924/com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger, PID: 3924
com.chaquo.python.PyException: AttributeError: module 'moviepy.audio.fx.all' has no attribute 'audio_fadein'
    at <python>.moviepy.editor.<module>(<string>:1)
    at <python>.moviepy.editor.<module>(editor.py:80)
    at <python>.java.android.importer.load_module_impl(importer.py:435)
    at <python>.java.android.importer.load_module(importer.py:353)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._load_backward_compatible(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:626)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:656)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:955)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:971)
    at <python>.java.chaquopy.import_override(import.pxi:18)
    at <python>.gif_convert.<module>(gif_convert.py:1)
    at <python>.java.android.importer.load_module_impl(importer.py:435)
    at <python>.java.android.importer.load_module(importer.py:353)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._load_backward_compatible(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:626)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:656)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:955)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:971)
    at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._gcd_import(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:994)
    at <python>.importlib.import_module(__init__.py:126)
    at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_Python_getModule(chaquopy_java.pyx:154)
    at com.chaquo.python.Python.getModule(Native Method)
    at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.newPost.visualMediaPost.VisualMediaPostFragment.moveFile(VisualMediaPostFragment.java:247)
    at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.camera.LifeCycleCamera.getFilePath(LifeCycleCamera.java:1161)
    at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.camera.LifeCycleCamera.stopRecordingVideo(LifeCycleCamera.java:1078)
    at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.newPost.visualMediaPost.VisualMediaPostFragment.lambda$onCreateView$5(VisualMediaPostFragment.java:162)
    at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.newPost.visualMediaPost.-$$Lambda$VisualMediaPostFragment$WS1G2y9p8sE-re_eOWFa7Rr0OCU.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26089)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I've found a fix for this problem (it involves [changing the python code](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/591) that would normally be generated by android studio, so any changes made to the python files will be overwritten during build time.

The python code is shown below

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

def convert(path):
    clip = VideoFileClip(path)
    return clip.write_gif("output.gif", fps=24)
```

The java code used to start the pyhton code:

```
Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(getActivity()));
        Python py = Python.getInstance();
        PyObject gifConvert = py.getModule("gif_convert");
        PyObject gif = gifConvert.callAttr("convert", file.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.i("gif type", gif.toString());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you mean by "the python code that would normally be generated by android studio", and how you are changing it.

Comment: when i say android studio generates the code, I mean that I don't download the source files and place them in my project manually. During build time, android studio searches for the relevant source files and adds them to the project. According to this solution, https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/591, I should just be able to comment out a block of code and add in some import statements to fix the problem.

Comment: OK, I think this link is necessary to understand the problem, so I've edited it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Chaquopy had a problem with `pkgutil.iter_modules`. This has been [fixed in Chaquopy 6.2.1](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/87).